# Using same function on twice in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, function

I am using a function to copy a row to another tab (sheet 2) and delete it from the source (sheet 1) tab. I want to use the same function on another tab (sheet3) and copy to sheet 4, but the function will only work on the first sheet (1). or not at all. Here is the function I want to use:

```
function onEdit1(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Sheet1
  // target sheet of move to named Sheet2
  // test column with yes/no is col 15 or O
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1 && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

}
```

```
function onEdit2(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Sheet3
  // target sheet of move to named Sheet4
  // test column with yes/no is col 5 or E
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet3" && r.getColumn() == 5 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }

}
```

I understand you cannot use the same function twice in a Google sheet, but you can combine them in to one function? I'm a newbie and not sure how to do that. I tried name the functions differently. Only one will work or neither.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some parameters to your function and change the parameters as needed. I added the parameters `copySheet`, `pasteSheet`, and `checkColumn. Every parameter should be a number. I replaced the numbers in the if statement with those new parameters:

```js
function onEdit(event, copySheet, pasteSheet, checkColumn) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Sheet1
  // target sheet of move to named Sheet2
  // test column with yes/no is col 15 or O
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet" + copySheet && r.getColumn() == checkColumn && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet" + pasteSheet);
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
onEdit(null, 1, 2, 15);
onEdit(null, 3, 4, 5);
```

I'm not sure what the context of the parameter `event` is, I'm assuming you know how to handle it.

Comment: Thanks for your response and answer. I forgot to mention, for the  Sheet 1 to move the row to Sheet 2, the checkbox to trigger the action will be on column 15, On the Sheet 3 to move the row to Sheet 4, the checkbox will be on column 5.

Comment: @AJay206 I added another parameter